# Android Studio - Starting and Stopping a Loop With a Button Press

Tags: java, android, loops

I'm new to using Android Studio, and am currently writing an app that makes use of sensors in the phone to control another device.  I searched and haven't found much that helps me address my issue.  Eventually I need to transmit the data I get from the sensors over a network, but I'm nowhere near that point yet so that's for another day.

Right now, the app can access the sensors and display it on the phone screen.  Each time the on screen button is pressed it updates the readings.  What I want it to do though is once I press the button once, continually update the values in real time as the phone is moved around.  If the button is pressed again I'd like it to stop.  Below is my current code in the main activity.  What I tried to do was use an integer that I would toggle each time the button was pressed and run a do while loop on one of the values.  When the do while loop is in there it won't do anything.  If I take it out, it runs like it originally did updating the values each time the button is pressed.  I also am displaying the value of "toggle" next to the sensor values and it is toggling when the do while loop isn't in there.  I don't understand why the do while loop won't run at all.  I also tried using a boolean value and toggling between true and false but I got the same result.  I also realize that the way the do while loop is set up it would probably not be able to be stopped, but I would've thought it would've at least entered the loop and kept running which would've at least got me started.

```
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.hardware.Sensor;
    import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
    import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
    import android.hardware.SensorManager;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.view.View;





    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    {
MySensorUpdateThread mySensorUpdateThread = null;

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mySensorUpdateThread = new MySensorUpdateThread(this);

    SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

    final float[] mValuesMagnet = new float[3];
    final float[] mValuesAccel = new float[3];
    final float[] mValuesOrientation = new float[3];
    final float[] mRotationMatrix = new float[9];

    final Button btn_valider = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    final TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    final SensorEventListener mEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        }

        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
                case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
                    System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, mValuesAccel, 0, 3);
                    break;

                case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
                    System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, mValuesMagnet, 0, 3);
                    break;
            }
        }
        ;
    };

    setListners(sensorManager, mEventListener);

    btn_valider.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            mySensorUpdateThread.toggleThread();
            if (mySensorUpdateThread.isRunning())
            {
                mySensorUpdateThread.start();
            }
        }

        });
}

public void setListners(SensorManager sensorManager, SensorEventListener mEventListener)
{
    sensorManager.registerListener(mEventListener, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    sensorManager.registerListener(mEventListener, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

public class MySensorUpdateThread extends Thread
{
    private boolean keepRunning = false;
    private String sensorResults = "";


    private MainActivity mActivity;

    public MySensorUpdateThread(MainActivity activity)
    {
        this.mActivity = activity;
    }
    public void toggleThread()
    {
        this.keepRunning = !this.keepRunning;
    }

    public boolean isRunning()
    {
        return this.keepRunning;
    }

    public String getSensorResults()
    {
        return this.sensorResults;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {

        int i = 0;
        int maxIterations = 100;
        try{
            while(this.keepRunning)
            {
                // This keeps the thread from going on too long in case
                if(i > maxIterations)
                {
                    this.keepRunning = false;
                    break;
                }

                // This causes the thread to rest for 50ms to
                // slow things down

                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e)
                {
                }
                SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(mRotationMatrix, null, mValuesAccel, mValuesMagnet);
                SensorManager.getOrientation(mRotationMatrix, mValuesOrientation);

                sensorResults = "Roll/Pitch (degrees): " + /*mValuesOrientation[0]*(180/Math.PI) + " "+ "," + " " +*/
                        mValuesOrientation[1] * (180 / Math.PI) + " " + "/" + " " +
                        mValuesOrientation[2] * (-180 / Math.PI);

                // Now post the results to the UI Thread
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        txt1.setText(getSensorResults());
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        catch()
        {
            Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I think your problem is not on while loop itself but on how you use it. I guess you're doing a non-stop while while waiting for a result, is this right? and also are you experiencing of freezing moment in your UI while running the for loop and literally feels like nothing happens?

Comment: Jace is right. You are blocking your ui during the loop. You need to run the loop in a background thread.

Comment: I have edited my answer to simplify the how the code works. Now I am simply keeping track of the number of iterations and posting that info to the txt1 TextView. This should give you a better understanding of what is going on and how to interrupter the thread.

Comment: I think your question has more to do with the efficient implementation of device `Sensor` and `SensorManager` rather than threading. I suggest you open a new question on that topic - I think you will get a better response and more informed answers.

Answer (score 0):

Put your sensor reading in a background thread. This is just an example. Make modifications as may be needed!

In your `Activity` class you will need to setup your background thread object:

```
MySensorUpdateThread mySensorUpdateThread = null;
```

In your Activities `onCreate()` method initialize the background thread by adding:

```
mySensorUpdateThread = new MySensorUpdateThread();
```

In your `onClick()` method start and stop you background thread:

```
public void onClick(View view){
    mySensorUpdateThread.toggleThread();
    if(mySensorUpdateThread.isRunning()){
        mySensorUpdateThread.start();
    }
});
```

Now here is the code for the background thread:

```
public class MySensorUpdateThread extends Thread{
    SensorManager sensorManager = null;
    private boolean keepRunning = false;
    private String sensorResults = "";

    public void toggleThread(){
        this.keepRunning = !this.keepRunning;
    }

    public void isRunning(){
        return this.keepRunning;
    }

    public String getSensorResults(){
        return this.sensorResults;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        if(sensorManager == null){
            sensorManager = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        }

        int i = 0;
        int maxIterations = 100;
        String mess = "";
        try{
            while(this.keepRunning){
                mess = "Number of iterations:  " + i;
                Log.e(TAG, mess);
                // This keeps the thread from going on too long in case 
                if(i > maxIterations){
                    this.keepRunning = false;
                    break;
                }

                // This causes your thread to rest for 500ms it might be a 
                // good idea to slow things down a bit -- just a suggestion
                Thread.sleep(500);


                // Get your sensor data here and set it to the 
                // local variable to be posted to the UI Thread
                //this.sensorResults = sensorString;


                // Now post the results to the UI Thread
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                         txt1.setText(getSensorResults());
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        catch(){
            Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

You will probably want to stop the background thread on the Activities `onPause()` method and perhaps restart it on `onResume()`.

Comment: Barns52 thanks for the info.  It makes sense what you're saying about using a background thread, but I am getting a little lost on setting that up.  I've taken your example code and modified my code to include that.  I am having some issues with variables being resolved and I'm sure I've missed something elementary here.  It's been quite a while since I've written any code and as I said earlier, I'm new to Android Studio. I keep trying to post my latest code.  How can I do that without using the "answer your question" link, or is that the only way to do it?

Comment: There should be an 'edit' link down toward the bottom of you answer. Use that to post any changes to you question or code.

Comment: I just added the updated code.  I have errors for the variables in the public void run() class(mRotationMatrix, mvaluesAccel, all of those).  I need to pass the values of those from the main activity to it, I assume with some sort of setter/getter method?  I'm not sure how to do about that though.  I'm looking through an old Java book that I have but the code examples are much simpler than what I have here and I'm having a hard time applying it to this.

Comment: I have not used the `SensorManager` class, so I don't really have any experience in implementing it. But my solution answers the question you posed "Starting and Stopping a Loop ...". I will have to take a look at the Sensor class.

Answer (score 0):

I found it helpful when I used handler thread for long time tasks, handler thread is androids official way for handling long running task. Here is the offical link
for more information on how to use a handler thread.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html

Comment: HandlerThread is basically just a wrapper for java's Thread class. Use whatever you are comfortable with.

Comment: handler thread is a wrapper yes but it is nifty with the things it provides, I would rather use a method that is official rather than implement my own threading because you never know who he might pass the code to next, if he is not working on the project on his own it is preferable he uses the official way. But to each his own.  Handler thread also helps prevent memory leaks by its process it uses.